# Generic function With<T> to do a one-liner using block

Tags: c#

I like this.  Anyone want to rain on my parade here?

```
public void LoadDatabasesTest()
{
    string[] args = new[] { "LoadDatabases" };
    ReportsService.Program_Accessor.Main(args);
    With(GetModel(), m => m.Databases.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name)));
}

void With<T>(T target, Action<T> action) where T : IDisposable
{
    using (target)
    {
        action(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What is more clearer here?

This:

```
using (Model model = GetModel())
{
    foreach (var item in model.Databases)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```

or this:

```
With(GetModel(), model =>
    model.Databases.ToList().ForEach(c =>
        Console.WriteLine(c.Name)
    )
)
```

You've defined some method so you could rearrange some things and add additional levels of indirection to run slower and more inefficient than if you had just written the standard way using the `using` and `foreach` blocks.  What did you gain here?  I'll tell you, *nothing*.

Any half-decent C# programmer should know what the `using` and `foreach` blocks do.  There should be no question about it.  Seeing your block of code, it's not so clear... we'd have to figure out what you're doing here.

What if someone saw your block of code and wanted to know what is going on?  I look at that and see `With`... "With" what?  What the heck is that supposed to mean?  If anything, it is only more confusing to people who are familiar with VB.NET's `With` keyword (which does something completely different).  The name isn't very great.  You should have given it a more descriptive name.  `UsingDisposable` might have been a better choice or something along those lines.

Don't even get me started on the ToList/ForEach combo... You can *never* go right doing this instead of using a simple `foreach` loop.  Why would to take a perfectly good collection, copy that collection into another list, just so you can call some method to do stuff with the added overhead of calling another method to do something on each item?  The `ForEach` method has it's place and that's *if and only if* you start out with a list in the beginning.  The overhead of the delegate is more forgivable here since that's what it was designed for.  I understand that this particular usage is just a "hack" just to make this loop work, but this should never be the answer.  If you *must*, write an extension at least.

See reason number two of Eric Lippert's ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).  The same can be said here twofold, both for the `With()` method and your use of `ForEach()`.

What happens if you need to do more than one statement in each of the blocks:

```
With(GetModel(), model =>
{
    HelloThere();
    model.Databases.ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
        DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
        DoSomethingElse();
    });
    DoMoreStuff();
});
```

Here come the braces again and even more typing when instead you could have just done:

```
using (var model = GetModel())
{
    HelloThere();
    foreach (var item in model.Databases)
    {
        DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
    DoMoreStuff();
}
```

Save yourself the grief, just use the `using` and `foreach` blocks.

Comment: Sorry if it seems I came on strong here, but I am fully against what you are doing here.

Comment: its cool, that's why i posted it to get perspectives, thanks

Comment: I'll tell you something else, thinking on the matter, I believe if my editor auto inserted closing braces for me, I would never have bothered with it.

Comment: +1 very good answer, I'm not savvy with C# but shouldn't it be Console.WriteLine(item.Name); where you use foreach? in the last code paragraph I mean.

Comment: @Dorin: You're right, I overlooked that change.  Thanks.

Comment: Looking at this again today, a defense for the staement that the additional indirection gains nothing might be that it builds in a naturally occuring interception point for statement(s) that use resources.  Another observation is that I could renamt With to Using to make it clearer.  Finally, I believe it falls into the category of micro opimiazation when comparing performance.  I really think for me it comes down to (a) wanting to be able to type certain bits of code on one line and (b) having a automatic nevative response to one liners with {}'s and single statement using/foreach/etc..

Answer (score 2):

You could also have just

```
GetModel().Databases.ToList()
    .ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Name));
```

instead of duplicating an existing function. ;)

(I like linq, but sometimes, what Jeff suggested is actually more readable)

But more importantly:

I don't see why you should have to dispose model. Do you have unmanaged resources within the model? If so, shouldn't `GetModel` dispose of the unmanaged stuff and return some plain old Clr objects to you as a model?

If the model is adapter(s) for SQLDMO or such, could you translate instead of adapting inside `GetModel`?

Comment: The model is an entity framework container with out-of-box code generation.  I have been assuming it could leak SQL Server resources if not disposed, but I admit I do not know this for a fact.

Comment: You're code is not the same. There is no call to Dispose() here.

Comment: That's why i question the disposing. The model shouldn't be disposed, the data context should be disposed. The entities returned from the context, as long as you don't need to lazy-load, does not need the context to be around. (undisposed)
Hence, dispose the context already in the GetModel() method.